# VBA - SQL Import From Excel Sheet To Access DB - EXECUTION ERROR 3343

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I would like to build a `SQL` request in order to store all my sheet content into an access DB in order to do this I built the following request :

```
 sSQL = "INSERT INTO Archive_FP21 (Date_Histo,Caisse,Libelle,Reference_Contrat,Date_de_Nego,Date_Valeur,Echeance_Finale,Libelle_Index,Taux_Actuel,Capital_Origine,Capital_Restant_Du,Marge,Taux_du_cap,Taux_du_Floor,Derniere_Echance_INT,Derniere_Echeance_AMO,Interet,Prochaine_Echeance) " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$A:R] IN """ & WbPath & """"
```

But I am facing the following issue :

> 3343 unrecognized database format
> [image]
>
> **[**I feel like my issue is in `FROM [Feuil1$A:R] IN """ & WbPath & """"`**]**

Below is the my full code Sub :

```
Sub archiver()
    
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sDb As String
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim WbPath As String

    
WbPath = "C:\******\Extraction FP21 Mise en Forme Auto\16102020 - Copie.xlsx"

sDb = "C:\******\BaseFp21.accdb"
Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(sDb)

sSQL = "INSERT INTO Archive_FP21 (Date_Histo,Caisse,Libelle,Reference_Contrat,Date_de_Nego,Date_Valeur,Echeance_Finale,Libelle_Index,Taux_Actuel,Capital_Origine,Capital_Restant_Du,Marge,Taux_du_cap,Taux_du_Floor,Derniere_Echance_INT,Derniere_Echeance_AMO,Interet,Prochaine_Echeance) " & _
"SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$A:R] IN """ & WbPath & """"


db.Execute sSQL

End Sub
```

**Note** The goal of this SQL request is to Add all data from the sheet 'Feui1.Range(A:R)` into my  Access Table.
I can't do it row By Row since I have 37K line to fill in Access.

What Am I missing ? How would you do in order to fill 37K row from excel inside Access DB with VBA ?

Comment: Where are you placing and running your VBA code? In the Excel file to be harvested or in the Access that will be the archive, or in a another file?

Comment: @Tech-On-the_Beach In an other file than the excel file which will be archived. And the access DB should store content of the file which need to be archived. But my VBA module is in an other workbook than the one storing data. Hope I am Clear Enough

Comment: @Tech-On-the_Beach I added a screenshot of the issue, hope this help ... I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query from an Excel workbook inline with an Access connection does not use the `IN` operator but bracketed identifier with set parameters such as headers and workbook type. As used, `IN` would work if you were querying an external Access database but being an Excel workbook, the database format was not recognized.

```vb
sSQL = "INSERT INTO Archive_FP21 (Date_Histo, Caisse, Libelle, Reference_Contrat," _
        & "                       Date_de_Nego, Date_Valeur, Echeance_Finale, " _
        & "                       Libelle_Index, Taux_Actuel, Capital_Origine, " _
        & "                       Capital_Restant_Du, Marge, Taux_du_cap, Taux_du_Floor, " _ 
        & "                       Derniere_Echance_INT, Derniere_Echeance_AMO, Interet, " _
        & "                       Prochaine_Echeance) " _
        & " SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & WbPath & "].[Feuil1$A:R]"

db.Execute sSQL
```

Also, be sure to avoid [`SELECT * FROM`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451) and explicitly select named columns especially in insert-select append queries for column-to-column mapping. `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ... FROM` is more readable and maintainable in case Excel columns order should adjust or some columns are no longer present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should the column name  of the excel file match with the DB field ? If no how would you do ?

Comment: No, generally in insert-select SQL queries names of inserted table do not have to match to names of select source but corresponding columns should align by data type.